# overlaySKScene can't notify the main SCNScene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a basic game that contains a `sceneView: SCNView` and a SKScene overlay `sceneView.overlaySKScene = OverlayScene(...)`.

When a button is tapped in the overlaySKScene I would like to notify the main sceneView to perform some animations and then start my game.

I have overriden the `thouchesBegan` in the overlaySKScene as suggested by Apple:

```
class OverlayScene: SKScene {

 override func touchesBegan(...) {

...
```

Now I want to observe this button tap and perform the animation:

```
observe(\GameViewController.sceneView.overlaySKScene.someProperty) { (selfRef, change) in
            selfRef.setGame(updatedState: someValue)
        }
```

but I can not observe the overlaySKScene and its properties.

What is the proper way to notify the `sceneView` from the `SKScene`?

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile, but I think I used protocols to solve this.  I wanted to change the gameState within different classes when an SKbutton was pressed.  It worked fine, but I wasn't doing that much with SKScene other than sound, so I eventually just did UIViews over the top of Scenekit, which was a lot easier if that's an option for you.  If not, then you might search for communication between view controllers, there are several options.